# ksh echo to stderr for specific statements

Tags: echo, ksh, stderr

I have the following shell script that echos output to the log and errors to err_file. However, I specifically want to echo some statements to stderr. Pls help

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "paramPassed: $0 $#" 

err_file="error_file.txt"
new_file="new_file.txt"

exec >> ${new_file}
#exec >> ${new_file} 2>${err_file}
#exec >> ${new_file} 2>&1

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    username=$1
fi  

userInfo=$(paramInfo ${username} | awk -F: '{print $2}')
echo ${userInfo} 

rcp ${err_file} mtvst32:/rcs/ver34/${err_file}

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        #This doesn't work. Need the following to go to console
        echo "UserInfo.SH FAILED copy to mtvst32" >> &2; 
fi
```

I wish to send the output of the last if condition to std err however, couldn't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that you're getting an error message. It would have been helpful if you posted it. However, this is likely to fix your problem:

```
echo "UserInfo.SH FAILED copy to mtvst32" >&2
```

Remove the space and one of the `>`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. That worked. what I actually wanted was this:
From the same code above

exec >> ${new_file} 2>&1

and send only the last echo statement to the console. Is there anyway to do that? 

In other words, all errors should go to the same file except for the following:
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        #This doesn't work. Need the following to go to console
        echo "UserInfo.SH FAILED copy to mtvst32" >&2; 
fi  
which I want to send to console. However in the above case, it goes to the new_file due to redirection.
Thanks.

Comment: @Kiran: Before your `exec >> ${new_file} 2>&1` (I ignored that because they were commented out in your question), add `exec 3>&2` to copy FD 2 to FD 3. Then your echo to the console will be `echo "..." >&3`.